# Link still underlined

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

there were so many questions about that but none of them are helpful for me. I want normal links blue and underlined while the titles for articles should be red and without underline. This is the code:

```
a {

  color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.field.field--name-title{
    color: #fffff0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried combine like: `a.field.field--name-title` and `.field.field--name-title a` but it doesn't work.

**@EDIT**
Adding HTML, this is the DIV with the article:

```
<div class="views-row">


<article role="article" about="/de/link-test" class="node node--type-blog-entry node--promoted node--view-mode-teaser clearfix">
  <div class="node__container">
    <div class="node__main-content clearfix">
      <header class="node__header">

                      <h2 class="node__title">
              <a href="/de/link-test" rel="bookmark"><span class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">LINK TEST</span>
</a>
            </h2>

                        </header>

            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><p>tu jest link <a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a></p>
</div>
        <div class="node__links">
    <ul class="links inline"><li class="node-readmore"><a href="/de/link-test" rel="tag" title="LINK TEST" hreflang="de">Weiterlesen<span class="visually-hidden"> über LINK TEST</span></a></li></ul>  </div>

          </div>
  </div>
</article>

  </div>
```

Comment: Add an example of the HTML code that doesn't work like you want to.

Comment: I can't edit the `HTML` becouse I am edditing the existing schema

Comment: can you try **!important** in text-decoration

Comment: @VikramPawar doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong selector. `.field.field--name-title` is the span inside the anchor tag. Given the markup you provided, try this:

```
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.node__title a {
  color: #fffff0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Better still would be to give the anchor tag a class and target that.

Comment: Seems I need to get more practice in inspecting via the web browser. Thanks, it works perfectly!

Comment: Wonderful! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If the link (i.e. `a` tag) does not have the `.field.field--name-title` classes itself, but is inside those elements, you'd have to write

```
.field.field--name-title a {
    color: #fffff0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

That would be the case if the HTML is for example

```
<li class="field field--name-title">
  <a href="something.html">Title</a>
</li>
```

If this doesn't apply, you really should post the relevant HTML code, even if you can't edit it, since we have to see the HTML structure in order to get the correct CSS selectors...

ADDITION AFTER HTML CODE HAVING BEEN ADDED:

In this case the selector should be

```
a.field.field--name-title
```

If that doesn't work, there might already be a rule with higher specifity in the CSS of your site, so you can extend it to

```
a.field.field--name-title.field--type-string.field--label-hidden  { ... }
```

And if that still isn't enough, you can add some more, like

```
.node__container .node__main-content .node__header a.field.field--name-title.field--type-string.field--label-hidden { ... }
```

Comment: If I do it like that (which i tried already) the color of the title is changing too

Comment: I added `HTML` where the article is

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.node__title a {
  color: #fffff0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-row">


<article role="article" about="/de/link-test" class="node node--type-blog-entry node--promoted node--view-mode-teaser clearfix">
  <div class="node__container">
    <div class="node__main-content clearfix">
      <header class="node__header">

                      <h2 class="node__title">
              <a href="/de/link-test" rel="bookmark"><span class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">LINK TEST</span>
</a>
            </h2>

                        </header>

            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><p>tu jest link <a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a></p>
</div>
        <div class="node__links">
    <ul class="links inline"><li class="node-readmore"><a href="/de/link-test" rel="tag" title="LINK TEST" hreflang="de">Weiterlesen<span class="visually-hidden"> über LINK TEST</span></a></li></ul>  </div>

          </div>
  </div>
```